# Break axis in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to display a line chart with a broken y-axis, using chart.js (2.3.0). In my chart, there's a fixed minimum value, which should always be shown as a label on the y-axis. I would then like to have the "empty space" between this minimum value and the minimum value in the dataset be removed. Is this possible to do?

Comment: A similar question has been asked: [adding-2-range-of-information-in-the-same-chart-chart-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386164/adding-2-range-of-information-in-the-same-chart-chart-js).  AFAIK there is no support in Chart.js for a broken axis.

Comment: This looks like it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249498/how-to-change-line-segment-color-of-a-line-graph-in-chart-js And this one is awesome as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621329/intersection-point-in-line-graph-in-chart-js