# Chartjs Line Color Between Two Points

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

[image: Example]

Is there any way to set line color of specific sections in between two points in chart.js?

I would like to color the section `00-07` gray, `07-15` red, and `15-23` blue.

Here is what I am passing as the `data` attribute in the `options` object to initialize the chart:

```
var chartData = {
labels: [/* a single dimensional array of strings */],
datasets: [
    {
        label: '',
        data: [/* a single dimensional array of totals */],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: '#e7eaeb',
        borderColor: red
    }
  ]
};
```

I think this is where I need to add the graph section points and colors, but I do not know how.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249498/how-to-change-line-segment-color-of-a-line-graph-in-chart-js

Comment: Look also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71468803/1635670    and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778552/1635670

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HI Michael Hurley I think you should use:

**interpolation**:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/interpolation.html

or

**Multi-axis**: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html

My idea is we have 3 datasets with multi-color,
End of dataset1 is first of dataset2.

Here my Example:

```js
window.chartColors = {  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',   orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',     blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',   grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)' }; 

var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Cubic interpolation (monotone)',
                    data: [0, 20, 20, 60, 60, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN],
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    fill: false,
                    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
                }, {
                    label: 'Cubic interpolation (default)',
                    data: [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 60, 120, 140, 180, 120, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN],
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    fill: false,
                }, {
                    label: 'Linear interpolation',
                    data: [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 120, 125, 105, 110, 170],
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Cubic interpolation mode'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            suggestedMin: -10,
                            suggestedMax: 200,
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        };

    
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just figured it out, I'll add a js fiddle in a bit.

Comment: Run Code Snippet you will get my example result.

Comment: @MichaelHurley you rock !

Answer (score 6):

Latest versions of ChartJS allow you to customize line segments individually, which can be used to change the color and also the style (dashed etc) of a specific segment.

```js
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: Utils.months({count: 7}),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [65, 59, NaN, 48, 56, 57, 40],
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      segment: {
        borderColor: ctx => skipped(ctx, 'rgb(0,0,0,0.2)') || down(ctx, 'rgb(192,75,75)'),
        borderDash: ctx => skipped(ctx, [6, 6]),
      }
    }]
  },
  options: genericOptions
};
```

See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/line/segments.html for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterLayout` hook to create a linear gradient through [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient).

In the following example, the linear gradient is created from the colors defined in `data.dataset.colors`.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
      var dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
      dataset.colors.forEach((c, i) => {
        var stop = 1 / (dataset.colors.length - 1) * i;
        gradientStroke.addColorStop(stop, dataset.colors[i]);
      });
      dataset.backgroundColor = gradientStroke;
      dataset.borderColor = gradientStroke;
      dataset.pointBorderColor = gradientStroke;
      dataset.pointBackgroundColor = gradientStroke;
      dataset.pointHoverBorderColor = gradientStroke;
      dataset.pointHoverBackgroundColor = gradientStroke;
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [101, 122, 103, 115, 95, 94, 100, 108, 112, 115, 119, 120, 109, 108, 105, 116, 117, 108, 109, 114],
      fill: false,
      colors: ['gray', 'gray', 'gray', 'gray','gray', 'gray', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="70"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your approach helped me to fix a problem with a gradient on the x-axis and zooming. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In V3 you can make use of the [`segment`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/charts/line.html#segment) option in the dataset to style specific line parts:

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [101, 122, 103, 115, 95, 94, 100, 108, 112, 115, 119, 120, 109, 108, 105, 116, 117, 108, 109, 114],
      segment: {
        borderColor: (ctx) => {
          const xVal = ctx.p1.parsed.x;

          if (xVal <= 7) {
            return 'gray';
          } else if (xVal <= 15) {
            return 'red'
          } else {
            return 'blue'
          }
        },
      },
    }]
  },
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="70"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been wanting to let everyone know a way for react chart.

```
import React from "react";
import { LineController } from 'chart.js';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

class MultiLineController extends LineController {
  draw() {
    const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    const meta = this.getMeta();
    const points = meta.data || [];
    const colors = this.getDataset().colors || [];
    const area = this.chart.chartArea;

    colors.forEach((color, idx) => {
      meta.dataset.options.borderColor = color;
      meta.dataset.draw(ctx, area, idx, 2);
    });
    meta.dataset.draw(ctx, area, colors.length, points.length - colors.length);
  }
}
MultiLineController.id = "multicolorLine";
MultiLineController.defaults = LineController.defaults;

Chart.register(MultiLineController);

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'multicolorLine',
      data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
          label: "My First dataset",
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
          colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
        }]
      },
      options: {}
    });

    return () => window.lineChart.destroy();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{width: '100%', height: 300}}>
      <canvas id="line-chart" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is screenshot of this chart.
[React Chart Component implemented by chart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKEIO.png)