# chart.js: issue with concatening two line charts

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to change the color of a part of a line chart in chart.js. I followed these posts:

> [How to change line segment color of a line graph in Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249498/how-to-change-line-segment-color-of-a-line-graph-in-chart-js)

And

> [Chartjs Line Color Between Two Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120036/chartjs-line-color-between-two-points)

I am close to achieving the proper result, however, the second line does not want to begin at the end of the first one.

[image]

Here is the code that is problematic:

```
var myChart5 = new Chart(ctx5, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: document.getElementById('tag4').textContent == 'ITEMS IN DIFFICULTY' ?
            ['90 days backward','60 days backward','30 days backward','30 days forward'] :
            ['90 days backward','60 days backward','30 days backward','30 days forward'],
        datasets: [{
            labels: labels8,
            data: defaultData8,
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 1                            
        }, {
            label: labels18,
            data: defaultData18,
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }],
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Quantity Sold'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]           
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here is what the data looks like:

```
"labels8": [
    "90_days_backward",
    "60_days_backward",
    "30_days_backward"
],
"default8": [
    129259.0,
    149651.0,
    70699.0
],
"labels18": [
    "30_days_backward",
    "30_days_forward"
],
"default18": [
    70699.0,
    109145.6
]
```

I am a bit confused about how to proceed, I have tried include "NaN" values in the second dataset to push it forward but it won't make the trick. Would someone has a clue on how to fix this problem?

Comment: You seem to have two datasets, which means two lines in the chart, is that your intent? Or did you mean to extend the existing dataset to have more data. If not, then maybe you should fill the second dataset with `null` just right so it starts where the other one ends.

Comment: In other words you can try something like:
`data.default8.forEach(() => { data.default18.unshift(null); });`

Comment: exactly, i want the second to start where the first one begins, I tried filling as such ```data: [NaN, NaN, defaultData8] but it does not work. I cannot really modify the dataset before it is called.

Comment: I'll try this out, where should i place this line of code?

Comment: Right after you receive the data and before feeding it to the chart datasets.

Comment: I've provided an answer that does what I suggested, but right in the chart configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the second line to start at the end of the first, its data array needs to skip those values. What you can do is fill the second array with `null` as many times as the first array has values.

In your chart configuration pasted above, in the second dataset, here is how you can assign the `data` property:

```
// to start right after the end of the previous line
data: defaultData8.slice().fill(null).concat(defaultData18)

// to start on top of the end of the previous line
data: defaultData8.slice(1).fill(null).concat(defaultData18)
```

This will copy the first data array (too keep the original intact), override all its values with `null`, the concatenate it with second like data, then assign it to the `data` property of the second dataset.

Comment: this is close to work! the only thing is that it is pushing the second dataset  too far. it begins at "30 days forward" instead of the point before that. I am very new to javascript so I am not sure how to fix it but its progress

Comment: If you want it to start on top of the end of the previous dataset, you can change `slice()` to `slice(1)`. Does that work?

Comment: that works thank you! Useful technique that you taught me thanks again